# What's the best way to load a script from a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an application where I load a div via an ajax call, or with jquery

```
$('#cont').load("something.html");

<div id="cont">
</div>
```

something.html looks like:

```
<script src="./js/test.js"></script>    
<table>
    .......blah....blah
</table>
```

I get:
jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

I have been going into the test.js file and just cutting and pasting the script to the beginning of something.html but this is a lot of redundant script.  Many pages uses it and it becomes a pain to maintain.

Is there a way I can keep script loaded this way in a separate .js file?

Comment: hi james, this is the best: <script src="./js/test.js"></script>  because that's how it's normally done.

Comment: It depends.  You could use a loader like AMD, you could bundle scripts with browserify, you could create a `<script>` and set the `src` your self after putting into the page, you could use jQuery `.load()` like you're doing right now.  It is incredibly dependent on use case.  I want to know why your getting the synchronous warning though.  I don't think `.load()` can load synchronously.  There isn't even a property to allow you to do it as far as I know.

Comment: I understand that I am getting the error by loading the script from an external file, while being loaded into a div... for example index.html has a div, and I load it with jquery.  the file I load is looking for an external file itself...  when I take the file contents and just put them in the beginning instead of calling a centralized .js file - everythings ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When jQuery inserts HTML that contains `<script>` elements, it executes the scripts immediately. If it's a reference to an external script, it uses synchronous AJAX to load the script recursively, to emulate the way the browser loads scripts as it's loading an HTML file. This triggers the warning.

You could just ignore the warning, as synchronous AJAX isn't going away any time soon. But if you really want to get rid of it, you could split your load into two parts. Take the line that loads `test.js` out of `something.html`, and use:

```
$.getScript('./js/test.js', function() {
    $("#cont").load('something.html');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking this into two operations. In your page, load your JS script using a normal script element with a reference to an external JS file:

```
<script src="./js/test.js"></script>
```

Then, do an AJAX call to get your content and load that into the target div in the AJAX call's success handler. The easiest way to do that in jQuery is with `$.get()`:

```
<script>
    $.get('/path/to/something.html', function(data) {
        // set the contents of #cont to the HTML returned from the AJAX call
        $('#cont').html(data);  
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If synchronous execution is not necessary for the script, you could try:

```
<script src="./js/test.js" async="async"></script>    
<table>
    .......blah....blah
</table>
```

Doing this means that there's no guarantee that your script would execute before the following `<table>` is parsed and rendered. Setting the `async` attribute means this can happen in any order.

The HTML5 spec is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async):

> The **async** and defer attributes are boolean attributes that indicate
>   how the script should be executed. The defer and async attributes must
>   not be specified if the src attribute is not present.
>
> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these
>   attributes. If the **async** attribute is present, then the script will be
>   executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the async
>   attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the
>   script is executed when the page has finished parsing. If neither
>   attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed
>   immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

[Support is pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-async) for modern browsers:

- IE 10+
- FF 3.6+
- Chrome 8+
- Safari 5.1+
- Opera 15+

Comment: excellent explanation! I will make to to +1 it when I hit 15! Thx

Comment: @JamesBailey Glad it was enlightening :)